# ServiceStack serialisation of long int value

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-text

I have an object with an attribute defined as long and the exact value is `635980054734850470` but when it gets serialised the JSON output gives me `635980054734850400`

It seems to be consistently dropping the last two digit values, rather than giving me the exact, value. Is there any reason for this?

Here's the example C# code:

```
[Route("/timestamp", Verbs = "GET")]
public class GetTimestamp : IReturn<TimestampData>
{

}

public class TimestampData 
{ 
    public long Timestamp { get; set; }
}

public class TimestampService : CustomerServiceBase
{
    public object Get(GetTimestamp request)
    {
        var timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
        Console.WriteLine(timestamp);
        return new TimestampData() { Timestamp = timestamp };
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
{"Timestamp":635984646884003500}
```

Notice the output always rounds to the nearest 100.

Comment: Please post the JSON and C# code you're using. Please try to always provide a [minimal verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking support questions.

Comment: @mythz sorry I've added the example c# and sample JSON output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON Serializer is working as expected:

```
var json = "{\"Timestamp\":635980054734850470}";
var dto = json.FromJson<TimestampData>();
dto.ToJson().Print(); //= {"Timestamp":635980054734850470}
```

And so is the JSON Service Response which you can see by adding `.json`, e.g:

```
/timestamp.json
```

Or viewing the response in Web Inspector, Fiddler or other packet inspector.

The only time I see it rounding is in ServiceStack's auto [HTML5 Report Format](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/HTML5ReportFormat) pages which parses the JSON response into a JavaScript object, e.g:

```
var model = {"Timestamp":635980054734850470};
```

Which creates a JavaScript object containing:

```
{Timestamp: 635980054734850400}
```

This is because numbers in JavaScript are stored as doubles where the [highest integer it can store without losing precision](http://www.2ality.com/2012/04/number-encoding.html) is `9007199254740992` which as it's less than `635980054734850470` it ends up losing some precision.